# Как подключиться с локальной машины к диску виртуальной машины запущенной на VPS?

Tags: vps, виртуальная-машина, vds, rdp

На локальной машине установлен Windows 10. На виртуальной машине, которая работает на VPS хостинге Windows Server 2016.
Подключаюсь по RDP для запуска программ, при этом создаётся массив данных/файлов на виртуальной машине, к которому хочется получать доступ с локального компьютера (как к сетевому диску).

Какие службы нужно включить на виртуальной машине?
Как настроить подключение к сетевому диску с локального компьютера?
Стоит ли использовать специализированное ПО?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в данном случае стоит смотреть в сторону FTP и WebDAV.
Мануалов по установке и тд довольно много.

Однако может и понадобиться какое-либо ПО, если пробросить порты не удастся. Я в своё время использовал HAMACHI, который поднимает VPN и уже можно напрямую обращаться к серверу.